# how to update CRUD controller generated with symfony 2.4 console

Tags: symfony, console

I generated my Controllers/Forms in Symfony 2.4 with following command:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud bundle:Entity
```

Now I made some changes in the entity class and would like to run this command again but I always get

```
[Runtime Exception]
Unable to generate the controller as it already exists.
```

even if I remove the appropriate files in `./Controller` and `./Form`

Comment: try adding `--with-write`

Comment: @Chausser, I think that the correct is `--overwrite` and not `--with-write`.

Comment: You are correct, the documentation didnt have that option in there, but it is indeed and option in the source. I submitted a PR to have the docs updated we will see if it happens.

Comment: --with-write is something different though.
You get asked when creating CRUD pages if you wan't to add "Write" stuff, such as Create/Update/Delete. If you say no it only creates Read (index/show) Actions. --with-write is the "no-interaction" version of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake. Other than written in the question I forgot to remove the controller.php file.

The `php app/console doctrine:generate:crud` script checks if the file `src/vendor/bundle/Controller/xController.php` exists. If it does it won't generate the Controller/Forms again. A further execute of `php app/console doctrine:generate:crud` (if xController.php doesn't exist anymore) will overwrite all other related files (eg. ./Form/xType.php or ./views/X/y.html.twig)

Answer (score 11):

to update generated CRUD you can use `--overwrite`.

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:crud bundle:Entity --overwrite
```

Comment: I recognized that using the --overwrite param does not overwrite / re-generate the Forms.